# SQL Select to return one line multiple times based on a number within the dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

So I've tried many other attempts at answers around this topic from here and so far everything has either outright failed or not given me the result I'm after:

I have a select statement to use for a report that brings through delivery information. The result set is from a main table that only has one line per delivery number (the delivery header record) and within the dataset there is also a field called palletspaces which we use to indicate (you guessed it) how many pallets are needed for the delivery

What I now need to do is the following:

1. find that palletspaces number
2. return the single delivery record the same number of times as that palletspaces number
3. include a new column in the results that counts up to that palletspaces number

so for instance, my SQL will return every record from the deliveries table and would look something like this

```
id          traderid    toaddressid county         postcode palletspaces
D-124597    2101        2           READING        RG6 1AZ  3
D-124600    20060       12          MAGOR, GWENT   NP26 3DF 1
D-124601    20060       13          RUGBY          CV23 8YH 2
```

So now, I'd need to see that palletspaces number, then return the particular line that many times and then also have a new column that counts these instances:

```
id          traderid    toaddressid county         postcode palletspaces    LineCount
D-124597    2101        2           READING        RG6 1AZ  3               1
D-124597    2101        2           READING        RG6 1AZ  3               2
D-124597    2101        2           READING        RG6 1AZ  3               3
D-124600    20060       12          MAGOR, GWENT   NP26 3DF 1               1
D-124601    20060       13          RUGBY          CV23 8YH 2               1
D-124601    20060       13          RUGBY          CV23 8YH 2               2
```

The other thing to mention is that naturally I'll have hundreds of different delivery records (all returned as one line each) and all will have differing palletspaces numbers. And of course stating the obvious I need the line to only replicate and count based on it's own palletspaces number

The SQL in use is as below

```
select 

deliveries.id,
deliveries.traderid,
customers.name,
deliveries.toaddressid,
deliveries.eutransportid,
deliveries.street,
deliveries.city,
deliveries.county,
deliveries.postcode,
delivery_custom.palletspaces,
ectransport.ectranspdesc

from deliveries

INNER JOIN customers ON
deliveries.traderid = customers.id
INNER JOIN delivery_custom ON 
deliveries.id = delivery_custom.id
INNER JOIN ectransport ON
deliveries.eutransportid = ectransport.ectranspcode
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @D-Shih I've updated the original question to add a clearer record set with multiple lines and differing pallet spaces as well as that same dataset in the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select deliveries.id,
    deliveries.traderid,
    customers.name,
    deliveries.toaddressid,
    deliveries.eutransportid,
    deliveries.street,
    deliveries.city,
    deliveries.county,
    deliveries.postcode,
    delivery_custom.palletspaces,
    ectransport.ectranspdesc
INTO #MyTemp
from deliveries
INNER JOIN customers ON
deliveries.traderid = customers.id
INNER JOIN delivery_custom ON 
deliveries.id = delivery_custom.id
INNER JOIN ectransport ON
deliveries.eutransportid = ectransport.ectranspcode


;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT id,traderid,toaddressid,county,postcode,palletspaces,1 AS LineCount 
    FROM #MyTemp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,traderid,toaddressid,county,postcode,palletspaces,LineCount+1 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE LineCount<palletspaces
    )
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY id, LineCount;

DROP TABLE #MyTemp
```

Hope this time you get it.

Comment: So close! On the face of it this works perfectly. However I've just tried to run it a second time and get "There is already an object named '#MyTemp' in the database" which is an issue, as this SQL will technically be re-run many times through the report, and indeed without re-running the SQL there's no way for me to select any new data as deliveries are created :(

Comment: that may well do the trick, but because I've already run the statement I still can't re-run it at the moment to see if the update will work, same error. I tried just running DROP TABLE #MyTemp in a separate query window and get "Cannot drop the table '#MyTemp', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." Is there a way I can clear this on it's own so I can test the update to your answer works?

Comment: @eddie_head01, Nope. You have to write the drop query in the same window only.

Comment: ah ok. So I think I might just do something very untidy and just change #MyTemp to something else :/ that at least appears to work from within SQL, now to see if it works within the report. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Recursive CTE`, we can achieve this:

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE ([D Number] VARCHAR(20) ,customer INT, postcode VARCHAR(20), palletspaces INT)

INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES('D-123456' ,19114, 'DA12 1TF' , 4)
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES('D-111111' ,19114, 'DDDD 1TF' , 3)

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [D Number],customer,postcode,palletspaces,1 AS A 
    FROM @TAB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [D Number],customer,postcode,palletspaces,A+1 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE A<palletspaces
    )
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [D Number], LineCount;
```

**Output:**

```
D Number    customer    postcode    palletspaces    LineCount
D-123456    19114       DA12 1TF    4               1
D-123456    19114       DA12 1TF    4               2
D-123456    19114       DA12 1TF    4               3
D-123456    19114       DA12 1TF    4               4
```

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this a few times here and there but have never gotten it to work outside of specifying data. for one I need to declare the entire SQL that I've posted, and secondly I can't specify the INSERT INTO values, I need those values driven by the SQL

Also the SQL statement is being run from a report, not from within SQL itself (whether that makes a difference or not)

Comment: @eddie_head01, What is the problem you face while trying this?

Comment: I think the problem is my lack of knowledge to be honest! the main thing is that I'd need the dataset to come from the SQL select, not from manual entry, and I can't get that part to work at all. So I'm looking at DECLARE @TAB (select x from y) or similar. But I've also tried using the select statement as part of the insert into with no joy either

Comment: @eddie_head01, The Query you give in your question, gives the result. Right?

Comment: yes, albeit I've removed some of the columns with long data just for readability. But the concept is that the query in the question gives me all the columns for the results that I then want to pass into the @TAB values so that I can run your magic

Comment: @eddie_head01, I don't want to disturb the existing answer. So I give a new solution for you. Try that and update the feedback in comments.